# What `(start: number)` in this code snippet means and what is the concept behind it

Tags: typescript

The below code snippet is taken from typescript documentation.In the below code snippet what does (start: number) mean.What do we call this type of declaration.Please help me understand this.I didn't find any explanation for this anywhere.

```
interface Counter {
  (start: number): string;
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
}

function getCounter(): Counter {
  let counter = function (start: number) {} as Counter;
  counter.interval = 123;
  counter.reset = function () {};
  return counter;
}

let c = getCounter();
c(10);
c.reset();
c.interval = 5.0;
```

I am also confused with this part too `let counter = function (start: number) {} as Counter;` why does this function don't have a name

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically it's a [Function interface](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#function-types).

```
  (start: number): string;
```

An above line describle function parameters and a return type:

- `start` is a param name
- `number` is a param type.
- `string` is a return type.

There can be more params:

```
interface Counter {
  (start: number, stop: number, desc: string): string;
}
```

Two other lines:

```
  interval: number;
  reset(): void;
```

describes function properties. In JS functions are objects, so this can have thier own properties - just like any other JS objects.